# ImportError: No module named skimage.io

Tags: python, import, scikit-image

I have already installed my scikit-image on my following path:

```
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-image in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (0.14.0)
```

This is what I can get when I type `pip install scikit-image` on my mac terminal

However, whenever I run the following:

```
import skimage.io as io
```

It keeps returning error as below :

```
ImportError: No module named skimage.io
```

What would be the cause of this import failure?

Comment: Are you using virtualenv for running your code?

Comment: @NitinPrakash no I am not.

Comment: `skimage.io` doesn't contain `io`. Your import should be: `from skimage import io`.

Answer (score -1):

The problem of mine caused from the using python3.

Python3 shares different module path from that of python2.

Comment: You can use `pip3 install scikit-image`, though, I think people will strongly recommend you use some kind of virtual environment or conda.